# What is your experience working for IT outsourcing company in the professional sevices and/or managed services?

Tags: business

I am from the UK. I have about 4 years experience working for a large European IT outsourcing company. This company was split into two; professional service and managed service. I only worked in the managed services and there was a lot of resources issues concerning reaching customer's expectation and there was a lot of conflict priority. I didn't enjoy may experience as a lot of arguments were involved with all internal parties and conflict of interest with external customers, legal matters etc.

I do think now that perhaps, as a employee, I do not want to work in IT outsourcing company and just work for a company that handle its own IT services. I am wondering what has your experience been like? Are you or have you worked in the professional services or managed services? what was your experience like? Have you worked in both services and what is your preference?

Look forward to your responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now this is water on my mill.

I have never worked for an IT outsourcing company, and your post just reminds me what's wrong with that industry. I have always maintained that any company who has enough work to employ at least one person full time is better off hiring that full time person than outsourcing their IT. And your post is proof of my thinking. Which will also answer your question.

When you work for an internal IT role, there is no conflict of interest. You work for a company, and IT is there to make this happen, as an internal service provider. You do your very best to make it happen, because your bonus depends on it, if the company pays a bonus. And if they don't, you still make it happen, because as a company it helps to achieve the primary goal: pay your salary.

When you work for an IT outsourcing company, all of this changes. The primary interest of that company is not to help their customers succeed, it's to make money. As much as possible. Which inevitably leads to the situations you have described.

This is not to say that there aren't resource issues in other companies. In fact, IT is usually one of the first to get squeezed. But, you still have the satisfaction of making it happen.

I have worked in IT in one way or another for the last 10 years of my career. And I find it very satisfying that with 10 minutes of my time, well applied, I can save somebody's day or week, or make things possible that otherwise would have been insurmountable for anybody else in the company. When you work in IT, you wield great power, and with that comes great responsibility. Use it with humility and you will be a happy man. Get the balance wrong, and it will kill you (mentally).

At the same time you are making a very good case (inadvertently) for starting an IT outsourcing company that actually cares about their customers more than the money they make from them.

Comment: "I have never worked for an IT outsourcing company, and your post just reminds me what's wrong with that industry. " I can't +1 hard enough

Comment: _"The primary interest of that company is not to help their customers succeed, it's to make money"_ - companies that operate this way may 'succeed' in the short-term, but eventually fail in the long-term. Customers are not stupid, and they talk to each other. _"At the same time you are making a very good case (inadvertently) for starting an IT outsourcing company that actually cares about their customers more than the money they make from them."_ <-- **yes** - because happy customers bring referrals and repeat business ==> even more money.

Comment: New customers generally offer a short contract. If they are satisfied then renewed contract is offered for longer period. This goes back to my point, the higher the value the contract the better the service the customer will get returned. I would of thought more people would have been interested in this topic, but hey that's me thinking, thanks wolfgangsz and Steve for your responses.